# Unable to pass variable value to curl command in preseed file

Tags: networking, server, bash, preseed

Here's my preseed late_command:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
in-target IP=$(ifconfig eno1 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}'); \
in-target curl -X post --data-urlencode 'playload={"text": "IP address is '$IP'"}' https://hooks.slack.com/incoming-webhook-url
```

In slack channel it prints only 'IP address is', value of $IP doesn't get printed.
How to pass on the variable value to slack? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

You have the `$IP` variable between *single quotes* (`'`).

That prevents shell expansion. For example:

```
# Without quotes
echo $IP
> addr:192.168.1.1
```

while

```
# With quotes
echo '$IP'
> $IP
```

Pass the `payload` string without quotes:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \ 
in-target IP=$(ifconfig eno1 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}'); \ 
in-target curl -X post --data-urlencode playload={"text": "IP address is $IP"}
```

Comment: I think in your first example `echo '$IP'` the quotes are wrong. Shouldn't that be `echo "addr:$IP"`?

Comment: @PerlDuck yeah, $IP was created with `IP=$(ifconfig eth0 | grep "inet\b" | awk '{print $2}');`, so the content was correctly `addr:192.168.1.1`.

Comment: @MrShunz Thanks for the response, but it still doesn't print $IP into slack. Is there anything I need to change?